Create function gives syntax error in Postgres
I am pretty new to PostgreSQL and also to Node-RED.
It seems like you can create tables with dynamic names in PostgreSQL. With something like this or this:
-- gives error: syntax error at »LANGUAGE«
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_per_meter(meter_secondary text)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$body$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
    format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meter_value_%I(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, v NUMERIC(21, 2) NOT NULL, d TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL);',
        meter_secondary) 
END;
$body$

I cannot spot the error here.
Is using RETURN QUERY EXECUTE wrong or overhead?
These examples look much more simple:
EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I '
   'WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2', tabname)
   INTO c
   USING checked_user, checked_date;

But my problems seems to be related to the way of function definition.


Error syntax error at »LANGUAGE« 2) plpgsql structue.  3) Also CREATE FUNCTION. See the problem? Hint LANGUAGE is in the wrong place.


Adding here, as a final nitpick: the last semicolon inside the body is optional at END; $body$ but the code's missing an obligatory one after it to terminate the statement: END; $body$; or END $body$;. In practice, most clients handle unterminated statements fine.

This is all messed up:

there is a semicolon missing at the end of the RETURN statement

LANGUAGE plpgsql is after AS instead of before it

the function is defined to return an integer, but you are trying to return a query result

RETURN QUERY is to return a result set, but CREATE TABLE returns nothing


(Thanks to Adrian Klaver for pointing out some of these errors.)
For the last two points, define the function as RETURNS void and remove the RETURN QUERY before the EXECUTE.
But there is a deeper problem with the function code: if you supply a string as function argument that is not an SQL standard identifier, you will get the double quotes in the wrong place. For example, for the argument CamelCase, the table name will become meter_value_"CamelCase", which is not correct.
Proceed like this:
format(
   'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I(...)',
   'meter_value_' || meter_secondary
)


The bigger issues  are 1) ... RETURNS INTEGER AS LANGUAGE plpgsql ...  which leads to syntax error at »LANGUAGE« and 2) ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function

Thanks folks! Right version is now (tested with calling function and doing INSERTS): CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_per_meter(meter_secondary text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  $body$ BEGIN   EXECUTE     format(         'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, v NUMERIC(21, 2) NOT NULL, d TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT date UNIQUE(d))',         'meter_values_' || meter_secondary); END $body$;
